# How to know if the deep learning model is overfitting or not?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision

I created a deep learning (CNN) model, I used data augmentation and two dropout layers (0.5).

How to know if the deep learning model is overfitting or not?

Comment: cross  validation

Comment: How to use cross validation in Keras??? @parvij

Answer (score 1):

Please consider going through other questions before posting a question. This will not only help you learn more by showing you multiple perspectives to a problem, but will also help you frame a clearer question explaining why the answers to other questions don't apply to your problem.

Refer [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81596/157555) for your answer.